# Twisted.web.server does not notify if a connection is cancelled by client

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, twisted.web

The [documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/interrupted.html) implies that the `Deferred` at `request.notifyFinish()` should be notified if the connection drops for any reason.  I loaded similar code below:

```
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.web.server import NOT_DONE_YET
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.logger import Logger

log = Logger()

class DelayedResource(Resource):
    isLeaf = 1

    def _delayedRender(self, request):
        log.info("Rendered!")
        request.write("<html><body>Sorry to keep you waiting.</body></html>")
        request.finish()

    def _responseFailed(self, err, call):
        call.cancel()
        log.info("No. Wait. Stop")

    def render_GET(self, request):
        log.info("Lets try this!")
        call = reactor.callLater(5, self._delayedRender, request)
        request.notifyFinish().addErrback(self._responseFailed, call)
        return NOT_DONE_YET
```

If I cancel the connection from the client, `_responseFailed` does not get called. The log statement "No. Wait. Stop" is never printed and the "Rendered!" statement *is* printed.

This is important, because in my real use case the I am allocating resources that need to be deallocated if the connection drops. After upgrading to twisted 17.1.0, these stopped getting cleaned up.

Am I doing this wrong? Or is this a bug in twisted?

Comment: It'd be nice if you completed your code snippet so it's a self-contained runnable example.  And, yea, the feature looks broken to me.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone are you saying this is a broken feature in Twisted or the OP's code? I've noticed something similar in the past and figured the browsers or OS was doing something and not cutting the connection.

Comment: Preponderance of the evidence is pointing to a bug in twisted, which is vexingly labeled "won't fix" https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/8692

Comment: @notorious.no broken feature in Twisted.  I didn't realize there was a closed-wontfix issue (as found by @matthew-scouten).  That the issue is closed-wontfix makes me sad, indeed.

Comment: Looks like the tide has turned on that Twisted issue.

Comment: Is Glyph a robot that doesn't sleep?

Comment: I happen to know two things.  (1) He is far more advanced technology than any mere "robot".  (2) He is capable of prodigious feats of both sleep and non-sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a bug (or an accidentally introduced feature - you be the judge!) introduced by http://tm.tl/8320 but recently fixed by http://tm.tl/8692.  Therefore, Twisted 16.3 through Twisted 17.5 will not fire `notifyFinish()` with a *`Failure`* (though it seems it still fires in the *success* case).  Due to complexities in the HTTP implementation and the underlying features of TCP, even versions of Twisted outside that range may not always fire `notifyFinish()` with a `Failure` in cases where the HTTP client observes some kind of error.  Bear this in mind and make sure that any processing that must occur at the end of a request does not rely on an *errback* on this `Deferred` (ie, attach a *callback* as well or ensure that processing runs as part of the response generation code).

Comment: Versions post Twisted 17.5 are supposed to be fixed? Good. Except it looks like 17.5 is the current highest version. I guess the answer is "wait until the next twisted version".

Comment: Indeed.  Though, to be safe, one could also test out master@HEAD and verify that the implemented fix actually provides the desired behavior (and then, if it doesn't, complain before the next release :).

Comment: We eventually got around to updating to a more recent twisted and the problem seems to be solved.